# stagewebview not working in flash builder(can't load a https link)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile

i new in this community and i am learning, i know that i ask newbie question but please enlighten me! in my tab view app(its a IOS app) i have a tab where i want to load a web page in app, i placed a button there "Refresh" when its pressed it pop a new view where i want to load a web link (https)! i watched some tutorials but i cant get it worked, here is the code for view with the refresh button
    `

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function butRefresh_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>

   </fx:Declarations>
<s:Button id="butRefresh" width="153" height="96" label="Refresh"
          click="navigator.pushView(cursHtml)" enabled="true" horizontalCenter="0"
          verticalCenter="9"/>
```

`
 and here is the view where the page should load '

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="cursHtml">       
    <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;
                protected function cursHtml_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
              {
                    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("https://www.alphabank.ro/ro/rate/rate_si_dobanzi.php"));
                  //        StageWebView.loadString(data.description);
             }

             /*  StageWebView = new StageWebView();
              //StageWebView.view = new Rectangle(dragBar.x, dragBar.y+20, 800, 600);
            //  StageWebView = stage;
            //  StageWebView."http://www.google.co.uk/"; */
            /*  StageWebView = stage;
                StageWebView.stage = new Rectangle(20, 100, 450, 450);
                StageWebView("https://www.alphabank.ro/ro/rate/rate_si_dobanzi.php");   */

                ]]>
         </fx:Script>



</s:View>
```

' i commented the last tries that i made! and a others i already deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done some strange things with the code:

- first - you cant use the same name as a variable name and class name, so `var StageWebView` is not allowed
- you used some non-existing properties/methods of StageWebView.

Try the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="cursHtml">       
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;
            protected function cursHtml_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
            {

                stageWebView.loadURL(data.description);
                //assuming that data.description stores URL
            }

            private var stageWebView:StageWebView;

                            //stuff below this line needs to be in a method body, also I see the viewport rectangle call is missing a close paren, adding it now
            stageWebView = new StageWebView();
            stageWebView.stage = this.stage;
            stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(dragBar.x, dragBar.y+20, 800, 6)
        ]]>
         </fx:Script>
   </s:View>
```

Comment: i tried your code and i get an error( i modified the code i little , i inserted the link in the stageWebView.loadURL("http......); but i get this error Description Resource Path Location Type
1042: The this keyword can not be used in static methods. It can only be used in instance methods, function closures, and global code. cursHtml.mxml /credite1/src/views line 16 Flex Problem
 for the stageWebView.stage=this.stage! what i did wrong?

Comment: maybe its something about that i should write public class cursHtml before protected function?